# How to Pass option from search into url

Tags: python, django

Currently i have a search that returns models matching the input. My goal is to add a dropdown to this search and pass that into the url for the use of separate views in one template.

So my search form would look like this

index.html

```
<form method="GET" action = "{% url 'app:search' %}">
 <input  name="q" type="text" placeholder="search by Key or Name"/>
 <select name = "category">
     <option value = "1"> Category 1</option>
     <option value = "2"> Category 2</option>
     <option value = "all"> All</option>
 </select>
  <input  type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
```

I need my urls to look something like this

urls.py

```
app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
        path('login/index/', views.IndexView.as_view()),
        path('login/index/<category option here>/search', views.SearchView.as_view(), name="search"),
        path('login/index/<category option here>/<slug:key>', views.ModelView.as_view(), name="detail"),  
    ]
```

I am able to grab the `key` and push that to the url on the search results page no problem like this

search.html

```
<ul>
    {% for x in results %}
    <li><a href = "{% url 'app:detail' x.key %}">{{x.name}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And able to grab the key by using a get function like so in my views

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.q = self.kwargs['key']
    return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But since category isnt part of this model's schema i cannot use this same approach(theres a complicated reason as to why it isnt)

**OVERALL**

I need to carry on the category option selected from the IndexView into the ModelView and be able to use that in my templates to create different pages like i have below, and hopefully use a `GET` function in my view to access the category and return context that gives me the category

```
<% if category == "1" %>
   <h1> CATEGORY 1 </h1>

<% elseif category == "2" %>
   <h2> CATEGORY 2 </h1>
```

EDIT: 
views.py

```
class SearchView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/search.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        q = request.GET.get('q','')
        for term in list(set(q.split())):
            self.results = Model1.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains= term) | Q(key__icontains=term))
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['results'] = self.results
        return context
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use django forms and a [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) for that?

Comment: Are the categories hard coded somewhere ?

Comment: I do realize that i should be using django forms/formsview, and i plan on changing to that, but for the short term i'm sticking to this if thats possible.....and the categories are hardcoded on the index page outside of the form options

Comment: Actually I do not understand why the categories need to be "searched" when they are hard coded (already known). Instead of a form those could simply be links with the url already containing the category.

Comment: Well unfortunately it is even harder to understand the actual problem :). What is the `SearchView` supposed to do with the selected category? Surely redirecting somewhere using the category in the url? Could you add the code of `SearchView`?

Comment: the searchview is passing the selected category into the url, so then i can create different pages on the same html file

Comment: The above edit doesnt have implemention of passing the category , it doesnt need to display or even use the category in the results as this model doesnt use or need the category value, the models with the foreign key matching the results does, its only for the use of the ModelView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189228/discussion-between-trixn-and-mfreeman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the searched category available in the `ModelView` this would be a way to achive that:

Extend your `SearchView` by passing the searched category into the context too:

```
class SearchView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    # ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['results'] = self.results
        context['searched_category'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context
```

Then you can use that in `search.html` to encode it into the url:

```
<ul>
    {% for x in results %}
        <li><a href = "{% url 'app:detail' searched_category x.key %}">{{x.name}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Adapt your urls like that:

```
app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/index/', views.IndexView.as_view()),
    path('login/index/search', views.SearchView.as_view(), name="search"),
    path('login/index/<str:searched_category>/<slug:key>', views.ModelView.as_view(), name="detail"),  
]
```

And now you can access the category in your `ModelViel` via `self.kwargs`:

```
class ModelView(...):
    @property
    def searched_category(self):
        return self.kwargs.get('searched_category')

    # use it in any view method with 'self.searched_category'
```

Comment: I thought of doing this, but couldnt figure out how to pass the `category` into the form action (`{% url 'kpi:search' %}`)

Comment: @Mfreeman I do not fully understand what you trying to achive in the first place. Why are those options in a form rather than simply links to the view with the url being generated if you already know all the categories? A search would only make sense if there are actually dynamically generated entries.

Comment: So my views aren't detailviews for a reason, i have to create querysets for multiple models, and the context im returning is a ton of querysets....with this in mind i wouldnt have to create a search view and display view with redunant contexts for each category, if i accomplish this, i am able to keep one view for the search and display on this specific model